# accessing key values from external file inside xsl

Tags: javascript, xml, xslt, xpath, loose-coupling

I have an xsl file and there are few variables inside a  javascript code( tag) which have hard-coded values.As I need to change the hard-coded values sometimes, I want these values in another file as key-value pairs and access it from within the xsl, so that I do not have to touch the main xsl file.
How can I achieve this?

Comment: Is that Javascript code in the transformation result, to be executed by a browser when it renders the transformation result? Or Javascript code to be executed by the XSLT processor? In the former case I wonder why you don't use `<script src="values.js"></script>` with `values.js` doing e.g. `var values = { "key1" : "value 1", "key2" : "value 2" };`. That would work in HTML with Javascript independent on how the HTML is generated.

Comment: Perhaps you could put the pairs in an XML document and use `xsl:document` to access them from your XSL? Or put them in a separate XSL file which you import or include at the top of your original XSL?